# PhoneGap get geolocation without sim card?

Tags: cordova, web-applications, geolocation

I'm developing an phonegap app and using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` method, I found that when I test this method in a phone without a SIM card, it always return a `Timeout expired` error.

But I found that another native app (like map app) can get geolocation, is there any way for phonegap app get geolocation without a SIM card?

Comment: in which platform are you testing?

Comment: @jcesarmobile my phone is nexus 5 with android 5.0 system

Comment: have you tried phonegap-googlemaps-plugin - https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin ?

Comment: @NehilMistry I didn't use Google map, so i haven't try it yet. I wonder if that possible to get geolocation when a phone didn't has a sim card.

Comment: On android, cordova just use the webview geolocation, so if something isn't working, you should search for another plugin with native code